# Differentiate a table according to a column value where there cant be any other entries on the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I got 2 tables where I keep location information and people's locations. I want to find rows that people who are inside without leaving the place. So I have client id and location id in the both tables. In my location table, I know which place is outside or not. Below query gives me people who are inside. If I make isOutside = 1, it gives me people who are outside. So the problem is that a person can have entries where isOutside is equal to 1 or 0. How can I differentiate people who have isOutside value 0 but don't have any entry where isOutside is equal to 1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(macID)
FROM locations a, logs b
WHERE b.location_id = a.id and b.client_id=1 and Date(b.lastLocatedTime) =  '2015-01-16'
and a.isOutside =0 and b.client_id = a.client_id
```

**Update**

I wrote this query which worked for me. It is similar to Bohemian's answer.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT macID)
FROM logs
WHERE location_id IN (SELECT id FROM locations WHERE isOutside = 0) AND client_id = 1 AND
                        DATE(lastLocatedTime) = '2015-01-16' AND macID NOT IN 
                        (SELECT macID 
                        FROM logs 
                        WHERE DATE(lastLocatedTime) = '2015-01-16' AND
                        location_id IN (SELECT id FROM locations WHERE isOutside = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `NOT IN` test:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(macID)
FROM locations a
JOIN logs b ON a.id = b.location_id AND a.client_id = b.client_id
WHERE b.client_id=1 and Date(b.lastLocatedTime) =  '2015-01-16'
AND a.client_id NOT IN (SELECT client_id FROM locations WHERE isOutside = 1)
```

Comment: I tried this however even it doesn't display people who have isOutside value 0, it doesn't mean they don't have isOutside value 0 in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join to outsiders and filter out joins, leaving just insiders:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.macID
FROM logs l
JOIN locations a ON l.location_id = a.id
  AND l.client_id = a.client_id
  AND a.isOutside = 0
LEFT JOIN (SELECT macId, l2.client_id, date(lastLocatedTime) lastLocatedDate
           FROM logs l2
           JOIN locations a2 ON l2.location_id = a2.id
           AND l2.client_id = a2.client_id
           AND a2.isOutside = 1) o
  ON o.client_id = l.client_id
  AND o.macID = l.macID
  AND lastLocatedDate = Date(l.lastLocatedTime)
WHERE Date(l.lastLocatedTime) = '2015-01-16'
AND o.client_id IS NULL
AND l.client_id = 1
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52314/15)

Here, logs is inner joined to location to find all insiders, but then outer joined to outsiders, which if not found will contain all nulls that the where clause selects (rejecting joins that were successful).

Also `DISTINCT` is not a function, so prefer not coding it as one; ie `DISTINCT macID`, not `DISTINCT(macID)`.

Comment: İt just displays all macIDs,it doesn't get rows where have only isOutside value 0

Comment: @AhmetTanakol well, it *should* work. Are you sure you hawe copied my query exactly? Especially the join types ("join" then "left join"). If you have copies my query properly and it really doesn't work, please create a [SQLFiffle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with your schema and some sample data.

Comment: @Bohemianyes I copied exactly your query. I think when you join location and logs it gets all people whose isOutside value is 0, however after your left join it doesn't eliminate the the ones with is Outside value is 1. The cell that you create before left join still can have entries in the second cell.

Comment: I wrote another query which is similar to yours

Comment: @ahmet my query should work. Your concern over joining is mistaken - it's supposed* to join to outsiders, by the *where* clause eliminate successful joins. Please post a simple SQLFiddle with some sample dara so I can find where the problem is.

Comment: I got it working. See link to fiddle (with irrelevant columns and tables removed)